# Django app for email

Tags: django

I'm working with PINAX and DJANGO building a ebsite.  That site has an email/messaging component in it and you can get an external email that is a copy of the email that is on the site.  (The email can contain URLS and some pretty formatting, and since it might be read outside of my site, I need the sent formatting to be HTML (so it will display correctly @ gmail and yahoo, etc....

I'm hunting for an app (or just some python code) that will clean the input email body f all the potential nasties so that I could safely display html in the message viewer.  Right now what happens is the escaper gets hold of the email body text and escapes all the tags so instead of seeing a list

- like
- this

you see

```
<ul>
    <li>like</li>
    <li>this</li>
</ul>
```

I'm looking for a pre-built set of code to clean the input email back to something sane.  I could write some regexes to do it, but I'm hoping someone else has already done that and has some tests for it.

I've toyed with the idea of forcing the writer to use markdown, converting the markdown to html and then displaying the message body as safe, but I'm still worried about missing one of the cases and letting a script/object tag thru.

I don't want to ban all html, just script tags, object tags, and well, maybe some others that I haven't thought of yet, which is why I'm looking for a pre-written package.  Any ideas on what I could use?

Comment: Be careful with tag whitelists - don't forget attributes - `<a href="#" onclick="dosomethingreallymean()">hello</a>`

Answer (score 0):

If you output a string and don't mark it as `|safe` it will have any html escaped and the tags will show up rather than being rendered.  However, this isn't what you want from a security standpoint.

Look at this discussion for more (see the snippet on the second answer).  What you want is a whitelist of tags you want to output, and remove the rest.  You must still be careful about javascript though:

[Django templatetag for rendering a subset of html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709801/django-templatetag-for-rendering-a-subset-of-html)