# best python lib to clean the tag (not safe), and keep the tag that i think safe

Tags: jquery, python, google-app-engine, tags

ex: i want to clean the "script" tag ,  but i want to keep the 'a' tag ,

so what lib you using to do this .

and i use jquery [cleditor](http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/) for WYSIWYG HTML editor ,  can it do  this for me  automatically ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that [**BeautifulSoup**](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) should do the trick, here.

Actually, here's a question + answers that's exactly about that : [Python HTML sanitizer / scrubber / filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699468/python-html-sanitizer-scrubber-filter)

Answer (score 3):

I have to do this automatically for a project of mine. The solution I have found is to use the [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) module to extract the script tag (I also do this for style and form).

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_string, convertEntities=BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES)

scripts = soup.findAll('script')   # find and return a list of 'script' entities
for s in scripts:
    s.extract()   # remove it from the DOM completely
```

Then, you can have BeautifulSoup print out or save the html.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, designed for sanitization, is [html5lib](http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/).

Whatever you do, do *not* rely on an editor component to do it for you: That runs on the client, so could easily be manipulated to submit invalid or malicious HTML!