# Sanitizing HTML in submitted form data

Tags: python, django, forms, sanitization

Is there a generic "form sanitizer" that I can use to ensure all html/scripting is stripped off the submitted form? `form.clean()` doesn't seem to do any of that - html tags are all still in `cleaned_data`. Or actually doing this all manually (and override the `clean()` method for the form) is my only option?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/699468/212218

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Django comes with a template filter called [striptags](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#striptags), which you can use in a template:

```
value|striptags
```

It uses the function `strip_tags` which lives in `django.utils.html`. You can utilize it also to clean your form data:

```
from django.utils.html import strip_tags
message = strip_tags(form.cleaned_data['message'])
```

Comment: "Note that strip_tags result may still contain unsafe HTML content, so you might use escape() to make it a safe string." - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.strip_tags

Comment: Strip_tags() alone is insufficient, and the strip_tags() + escape() combination makes for really ugly text-- especially where it legitimately contains apostrophes. Just use bleach.clean().

Comment: Is there any reason to strip tags? If a user is submitting tag like stuff it is probably better to escape it but keep it looking like the input. Say I enter stuff like `<sarcasm>bad joke</sarcasm>`

Answer (score 55):

`strip_tags` actually removes the tags from the input, which may not be what you want.

To convert a string to a "safe string" with angle brackets, ampersands and quotes converted to the corresponding HTML entities, you can use the [escape](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#escape) filter:

```
from django.utils.html import escape
message = escape(form.cleaned_data['message'])
```

Answer (score 35):

Alternatively, there is a Python library called [bleach](https://bleach.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html):

> Bleach is a whitelist-based HTML sanitization and text linkification library. It is designed to take untrusted user input with *some* HTML.
>
> Because Bleach uses `html5lib` to parse document fragments the same way browsers do, it is extremely resilient to unknown attacks, much more so than regular-expression-based sanitizers.

Example:

```
import bleach
message = bleach.clean(form.cleaned_data['message'], 
                       tags=ALLOWED_TAGS,
                       attributes=ALLOWED_ATTRIBUTES, 
                       styles=ALLOWED_STYLES, 
                       strip=False, strip_comments=True)
```