# Remove contents of <style>...</style> tags using html5lib or bleach

Tags: python, django, html5lib

I've been using the excellent [bleach](https://github.com/jsocol/bleach) library for removing bad HTML.

I've got a load of HTML documents which have been pasted in from Microsoft Word, and contain things like:

```
<STYLE> st1:*{behavior:url(#ieooui) } </STYLE>
```

Using bleach (with the `style` tag implicitly disallowed), leaves me with:

```
st1:*{behavior:url(#ieooui) }
```

Which isn't helpful. Bleach seems only to have options to:

- Escape tags;
- Remove the tags (but not their contents).

I'm looking for a third option - remove the tags and their contents.

Is there any way to use bleach or html5lib to completely remove the `style` tag and its contents? The [documentation for html5lib](http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/wiki/UserDocumentation) isn't really a great deal of help.

Comment: I wonder if bleach is capable of achieving this in 2019? According to the docs, I don't think so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turned out [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) was a better tool for this task:

```
from lxml.html.clean import Cleaner

def clean_word_text(text):
    # The only thing I need Cleaner for is to clear out the contents of
    # <style>...</style> tags
    cleaner = Cleaner(style=True)
    return cleaner.clean_html(text)
```

Comment: beware, using `Cleaner(stye=True)` implies using many default values... no?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to strip the contents of  tags using a filter based on this approach: https://bleach.readthedocs.io/en/latest/clean.html?highlight=strip#html5lib-filters-filters. It does leave an empty `<style></style>` in the output, but that's harmless.

```py
from bleach.sanitizer import Cleaner
from bleach.html5lib_shim import Filter

class StyleTagFilter(Filter):
    """
    https://bleach.readthedocs.io/en/latest/clean.html?highlight=strip#html5lib-filters-filters
    """

    def __iter__(self):
        in_style_tag = False
        for token in Filter.__iter__(self):
            if token["type"] == "StartTag" and token["name"] == "style":
                in_style_tag = True
            elif token["type"] == "EndTag":
                in_style_tag = False
            elif in_style_tag:
                # If we are in a style tag, strip the contents
                token["data"] = ""
            yield token


# You must include "style" in the tags list
cleaner = Cleaner(tags=["div", "style"], strip=True, filters=[StyleTagFilter])
cleaned = cleaner.clean("<div><style>.some_style { font-weight: bold; }</style>Some text</div>")

assert cleaned == "<div><style></style>Some text</div>"
```