# Python and HTMLParser.handle_data() - How to get data from tags?

Tags: python

I'm trying to parse a web page with the Python HTMLParser. I want to get the content of a tag, but I'm not sure how to do it. This is the code I have so far:

```
import urllib.request
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_data(self, data):
        print("Encountered   some data:", data)


url = "website"
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()

parser = MyHTMLParser(strict=False)
parser.feed(str(page))
```

If I understand correctly, I can use the `handle_data()` function to get the data between tags. How do I specify which tags to get the data from? And how do I get the data?

Comment: I recommend you to use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) because it has a really friendly interface.

Comment: Not just because of the friendly interface, though - it's much more forgiving of the kind of broken/incorrect HTML you'll see out on the wild wild web.

Comment: I tried BeautifulSoup. The page I parsed made it choke. What do you do when even BeautifulSoup won't work? :)

Comment: You can also [sanitize](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Sanitizing%20Bad%20Data%20with%20Regexps) your input with BeautifulSoup. Some more information in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/699468/183066).

Comment: What is the web-page you are trying to parse, and what data are you trying to extract?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
html_code = urllib2.urlopen("xxx")
html_code_list = html_code.readlines()
data = ""
for line in html_code_list:
    line = line.strip()

    if line.startswith("<h2"):
       data = data+line

hp = MyHTMLParser()
hp.feed(data)
hp.close()
```

thus you can extract data from h2 tag, hope it can help

Comment: Bad! Don't parse HTML with that!

Comment: What's the best way to parse HTML? I tried HTMLParser, the parsing speed is really slow

Answer (score 1):

```
class HTMLParse(HTMLParser.HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'h2':
            self.recordh2 = True
    def handle_endtag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'h2':
            self.recordh2 = False
    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.recordh2:
            # do your work here
```

Comment: is there no way to merely retrieve data between the tags? I mean, everybody advice to use BS or lxml, but I would like to try and use HTMLParser if it was possible, as my application is very simple (and as I would like to learn to do simple manipulations in the command line interface too)...

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to format/clean this up it but this is how I usually do it:

```
        class HTMLParse(HTMLParser.HTMLParser):
            def handle_starttag(self, tag, attr):
                if tag.lower() == "a":
                    for item in attr:
                        #print item
                        if item[0].lower() == "href":
                            path = urlparse.urlparse(item[1]).path
                            ext = os.path.splitext(path)[1]
                            if ext.lower() in (".jpeg", ".jpg", ".png",
                                               ".bmp"):
                                print "Found: "+ item[1]
```