# Jinja2 escape all HTML but img, b, etc

Tags: python, escaping, flask, jinja2

Jinja2 automatically escapes all HTML tags, but I want to not escape some tags (like `img`, `b`, and some others). How can I do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can write your own filter. The [*scrubber* library](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/scrubber) is pretty good at cleaning up HTML. The filter will need to wrap the returned string in `jinja2.Markup` so the template will not re-escape it.

Edit: a code example

```
import jinja2
import scrubber

def sanitize_html(text):
    return jinja2.Markup(scrubber.Scrubber().scrub(text))

jinja_env.filters['sanitize_html'] = sanitize_html
```

Comment: The scrubber library is unmaintained and does not support python3

Answer (score 11):

You'll want to parse the input on submission using a white list approach - there are several good examples [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699468/python-html-sanitizer-scrubber-filter) and [viable options](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bleach) out there.

Once you have done that, you can mark any variables that will contain HTML that should not be escaped with the `safe` filter:

```
{{comment|safe}}
```

Answer (score 9):

The [Bleach](https://github.com/jsocol/bleach) library can do very well.

For example, assuming the variable 'jinja_env' is in scope:

```
from bleach import clean
from markupsafe import Markup

def do_clean(text, **kw):
    """Perform clean and return a Markup object to mark the string as safe.
    This prevents Jinja from re-escaping the result."""
    return Markup(clean(text, **kw))

jinja_env.filters['clean'] = do_clean
```

Then in a template you might have something like:

```
<p>{{ my_variable|clean(tags=['img', 'b', 'i', 'em', 'strong'], attributes={'img': ['src', 'alt', 'title', 'width', 'height']}) }}</p>
```

You can also use a callable (instead of a list) in the attributes, allowing more thorough validation of the attributes (e.g. checking that src provides a valid URL). Documentation shows [an example](http://bleach.readthedocs.org/en/latest/clean.html#callable-filters).