# Newlines not being interpreted when getting from sqlite db?

Tags: html, sqlite, newline, flask

I'm using Flask and Sqlite.

I take some string, which contains newlines, and store it in the db. At some later point I get it from the db and include it on some page, and the string shows up without newlines. What's with that?

For example if I have

```
{{ entry.content }}
```

in my template, and the entry that was stored had content "hello\nhello", it displays "hellohello" on the page.

However if I have

```
{{ entry.content.replace('\r\n','<br />') }}
```

or

```
{{ entry.content.replace('\r\n','&#13;') }}
```

in my template, it will display "hello
hello" or "hellohello" on the page.

So my impression is that the newline characters just aren't being interpreted and displayed by the browser. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try {{ entry.content|safe }} so Flask/Jinja doesn't escape your HTML.

(Be careful, though, as any user entered content, including script tags, will be output as-is. If you really want to be cautious and only allow 
 tags you might want to do write your own scrubber: [Jinja2 escape all HTML but img, b, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976683/jinja2-escape-all-html-but-img-b-etc))