# avoiding malicious js in django using django-ckeditor

Tags: python, html, django, ckeditor

I am currently using `django-ckeditor` to allow users to enter a rich description for their profile.

However, this opens the door to malicious users that will try to do XSS and other code injection.

I was wondering what would be the best way to go about this?

I looked at [Python HTML sanitizer / scrubber / filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699468/python-html-sanitizer-scrubber-filter), but it seems that these solutions get rid of attributes such as "style=", which totally contradict the usage of `ckeditor` to have, for example, coloured text, or other stuff that depend on these attributes.

Should I use another tool instead of `ckeditor`? Or what can I do?

My main goal is to allow the user to show pictures, coloured text, etc in their "profile"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should decide and write a "whitelist" of what is allowed to post. Then, parse posted data thoroughly and clean up everything what is not in that whitelist. If it is some style - parse style attribute and remove everything except whitelisted stuff.

You can do it with old good BeautifulSoup, for example.

Surely, don't whitelist `<script>` tags or `onSOMETHING` handlers - they usually bring more pain than the gain.