# feedparser cant get youtube player

Tags: python, feedparser

I'm testing [`feedparser`](http://code.google.com/p/feedparser/) on my rss feed.
It works like a charm and I get all the entries.

Some news has an embedded youtube player, but this just does not appear in the return values of feedparser.

My code is simply:

```
d = feedparser.parse('http://feeds.feedburner.com/NotciasPs3evita-Mypst')
```

This returns (excerpt):

```
 guidislink': False,
          'id': u'http://mypst.com.br/forum/index.php?/topic/17336-gamegen-call-of-duty-black-ops-2-ganha-trailer-com-acao-real-e-muitas-surpresas/',
          'link': u'http://mypst.com.br/forum/index.php?/topic/17336-gamegen-call-of-duty-black-ops-2-ganha-trailer-com-acao-real-e-muitas-surpresas/',
          'links': [{'href': u'http://mypst.com.br/forum/index.php?/topic/17336-gamegen-call-of-duty-black-ops-2-ganha-trailer-com-acao-real-e-muitas-surpresas/',
                     'rel': u'alternate',
                     'type': u'text/html'}],
          'published': u'Mon, 29 Oct 2012 14:53:58 +0000',
          'published_parsed': time.struct_time(tm_year=2012, tm_mon=10, tm_mday=29, tm_hour=14, tm_min=53, tm_sec=58, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=303, tm_isdst=0),
          'summary': u'A Activision revelou hoje um novo trailer de Call of Duty: Black Ops 2, substituindo as cenas de a\xe7\xe3o do jogo por cenas de a\xe7\xe3o na vida real. O trailer traz diversas \u201csurpresas\u201d e alguns zumbis.<br />\n<br />\n<br />\n<br />\nCall of Duty: Black Ops 2 chegar\xe1 no dia 13 de novembro nos Estados Unidos.<br />\n<br />\n<br />\n<em class="bbc"><strong class="bbc">Fonte: <a class="bbc_url" href="http://www.gamegen.com.br/playstation3/call-of-duty-black-ops-2-ganha-trailer-com-acao-real-e-muitas-surpresas/" rel="nofollow external" title="Link externo">GameGeneration</a></strong></em>',
          'summary_detail': {'base': u'http://feeds.feedburner.com/NotciasPs3evita-Mypst',
                             'language': None,
                             'type': u'text/html',
                             'value': u'A Activision revelou hoje um novo trailer de Call of Duty: Black Ops 2, substituindo as cenas de a\xe7\xe3o do jogo por cenas de a\xe7\xe3o na vida real. O trailer traz diversas \u201csurpresas\u201d e alguns zumbis.<br />\n<br />\n<br />\n<br />\nCall of Duty: Black Ops 2 chegar\xe1 no dia 13 de novembro nos Estados Unidos.<br />\n<br />\n<br />\n<em class="bbc"><strong class="bbc">Fonte: <a class="bbc_url" href="http://www.gamegen.com.br/playstation3/call-of-duty-black-ops-2-ganha-trailer-com-acao-real-e-muitas-surpresas/" rel="nofollow external" title="Link externo">GameGeneration</a></strong></em>'},
          'title': u'[GameGen] Call of Duty: Black Ops 2 ganha trailer com a\xe7\xe3o real e muitas surpresas',
          'title_detail': {'base': u'http://feeds.feedburner.com/NotciasPs3evita-Mypst',
                           'language': None,
                           'type': u'text/plain',
                           'value': u'[GameGen] Call of Duty: Black Ops 2 ganha trailer com a\xe7\xe3o real e muitas surpresas'}},
```

Everything is in place except for the youtube player `<object>` tag. Is this a feedparser bug or a problem on my rss? Is there other lib on python to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The feedparser [sanitizes HTML input](http://packages.python.org/feedparser/html-sanitization.html) and `<object>`, `<param>` and `<embed>` tags are stripped by default.

You need to either disable sanitization (only if you truly trust the source), or whitelist the YouTube tags.

To disable sanitization, set `SANITIZE_HTML` to False:

```
feedparser.SANITIZE_HTML = False
```

To add to the whitelist, add elements to the `_HTMLSanitizer.acceptable_elements` set:

```
_HTMLSanitizer.acceptable_elements.update(['object', 'param', 'embed'])
```

Both methods have inherent risks, and you are opening yourself to attacks this way. The approach I'd use is to switch of sanitization altogether, but then use [some other method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699468/python-html-sanitizer-scrubber-filter) to sanitize the HTML, probably using `lxml.html.clean` with a whitelist and listing YouTube in `host_whitelist`.

Comment: It's actually `feedparser._HTMLSanitizer.acceptable_elements.update(['object', 'param', 'embed'])`, and the same goes for `feedparser._HTMLSanitizer.acceptable_attributes.update(['allowfullscreen', 'frameborder'])`. I wonder why I could not find this info in Feedparser's documentation.

Answer (score 1):

In response to the above solution, it looks as though more recently the SANITIZE_HTML setting has moved under feedparser.api:

```
feedparser.api.SANITIZE_HTML = False
feedparser.api.mixin.SANITIZE_HTML = False
```