# How to sanitize input to avoid malicious attributes in django?

Tags: django, django-templates, beautifulsoup

I'd like to allow users to post images so need to add `|safe` to template tags and use beautifulsoap to whitelist some tags using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/699483/4151875) snippet.

However I am wondering how to avoid potentially malicious attributes like the following?

```
<img src="puppy.png" onload="(function(){/* do bad stuff */}());" />
```

**Update:**
Note that the snippet linked above has some XSS flaws, mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/812785/4151875)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check against an attribute whitelist as well.

Using **Beautiful Soup 3**:

```
def safe_html(html):

    tag_whitelist = ['img']
    attr_whitelist = ['src', 'alt', 'width', 'height']

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

    for tag in soup.findAll():
        if tag.name.lower() in tag_whitelist:
            tag.attrs = [a for a in tag.attrs if a[0].lower() in attr_whitelist]
        else:
            tag.unwrap()

    # scripts can be executed from comments in some cases (citation needed)
    comments = soup.findAll(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment))
    for comment in comments:
        comment.extract()

    return unicode(soup)
```

Using **Beautiful Soup 4**:

```
def safe_html(html):

    tag_whitelist = ['img']
    attr_whitelist = ['src', 'alt', 'width', 'height']

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

    for tag in soup.find_all():
        if tag.name.lower() in tag_whitelist:
            tag.attrs = { name: value for name, value in tag.attrs.items() 
                if name.lower() in attr_whitelist }
        else:
            tag.unwrap()

    # scripts can be executed from comments in some cases (citation needed)
    comments = soup.find_all(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment))
    for comment in comments:
        comment.extract()
    return unicode(soup)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. What is `Comment` though?

Comment: It refers to HTML comment tags i.e. ``<!-- some evil HTML comment -->``. I've read that they can expose some vulnerabilities but I have no definitive evidence for it. In my example I extract them just to be safe.

Comment: you should use `find_all` instead of  `findAll` change fix that and have my vote:)

Comment: @Wenzil Actually this snippet filters out the `<img src...` and keeps only `<img/>` hence I unaccepted the answer. Any ideas to resolve this?

Comment: You're saying the ``src`` attribute is filtered even when whitelisted? I got different results with Beautiful Soup 3 & 4 so I updated my answer with a solution for each. Does that help you?

Comment: @Wenzil yes what remainded from image tag was just `<img />` but The new version sorted out the problem. Many thanks!