# How to display text with HTML-markup? (I use ckeditor)

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-ckeditor

I heard about the filter `|safe`, but if I understood correctly, that's unsafe and creates a backdoor for injections.

What are the alternatives to display full posts with formatted text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think when you not use the filter of `|safe`, then output should return as text only with html markup *(not rendered as html output)*.

But, if you need to exclude some dangerous tags such as `<script>location.reload()</script>`, you need to handle it with custom templatetag filter..

I got good answer from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/699483/6396981, via `BeautifulSoup`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from django import template
from django.utils.html import escape

register = template.Library()
INVALID_TAGS = ['script',]

def clean_html(value):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(value)
    for tag in soup.findAll(True):
        if tag.name in INVALID_TAGS:
            # tag.hidden = True # you also can use this.
            tag.replaceWith(escape(tag))
    return soup.renderContents()

# clean_html('<h1>This is heading</h1> and this one is xss injection <script>location.reload()</script>')
# output:
# <html><body><h1>This is heading</h1> and this one is xss injection &lt;script&gt;location.reload()&lt;/script&gt;</body></html>

@register.filter
def safe_exclude(text):
    # eg: {{ post.description|safe_exclude|safe }}
    return clean_html(text)
```

Hope it usefull..