# WYSIWYG editor for templates

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm looking for a wysiwyg editor for the front end of my django powered website (i.e. my html templates).

Using the wysiwyg editor, users needs to be able to:

- create bullet points
- create bold text
- change font size

Given these requirements, what WYSIWYG editor package would you recommend?

Also, I was looking at django-summernote. With this package, it looks like there is a requirement to mark content as safe when displaying that content in templates.

{{ foobar|safe }}

Do all wysiwyg editors require this? Does this represent a security concern? Could an end user insert malicious code into the textbox and then have it executed when the page is rendered? My end users are random people on the internet.

Thanks all!

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/42725293/11193405

Answer (score 2):

you can use [Tiny Mce](https://django-tinymce.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

basically **safe** marks a string as not requiring further HTML escaping prior to output. When autoescaping is off, this filter has no effect.